# Shifting columns of the array

Tags: c, arrays

I am looking to shift all the columns that contain all one's to the right, and have all the columns other to be shifted to the left most. Here is an example of what I want to achieve (on the left and the result on the right:

nb. ONLY the columns containing ALL one's are moved to the right.

```
12112111111211
12112111111211
11112112111211
11112111111211
```

and the result:

```
22121111111111
22121111111111
12221111111111
12121111111111
```

My attempt so far: 
check = 1;

```
for (i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= column; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] != '1'){
            check = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (check) {

    for (j = 1; j < width; j++)
        for (i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            if (array[i][j] == '.') {
                array[i][j] = array[i][j+1];
                array[i][j+1] = '1';
           }
}
```

At the moment it's only both columns to the left once, and I understand why, but I'm not sure how to overcome this problem

Comment: Can You fix Your code a little bit because You have mixed dims: height, column and width. and magic chars '.' that dont exist in Your example. Please paste compiling C code and We will help You to solve problem or use other ready algorithm like vik post.

Comment: OK, now let me ask you this: How can `array[i][j]` ever be equal `'.'`???

Comment: So you have an array of columns to be sorted. Why not have a look at `qsort()`, which does just that: sort an array's elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to bring columns that are not all 1 to first. Try following:

```
int colIndex = 0;
for(int c = 0 ; c < numOfCols ; c++)
{
    if(col c is not all 1)
    {
        swap column c with column colIndex;
        colIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following algorithm:

```
for r = 0 to rows - 1
    c_first = 0
    for c = 0 to cols - 1
        if arr[r][c] == 2
            if c > c_first
                swap(arr[r][c] and arr[r][c_first])
                c_first++
```

EDIT:

```
for c = cols - 1 to 0
    c_last = cols - 1
    if c has all rows = 1 AND c < c_last
        swap columns c and c_last
        c_last -= 1
    else if c has all rows = 1 AND c = c_last
        c_last -=1
```

This is not such a clean algorithm, but should work.